# Android Gallery doesn't get refreshed, once an image is deleted out of it

Tags: android, gallery

I want to delete an image from the gallery and for some important reasons i added my delete activity  in the share button of the gallery with the following intent filter

```
 <intent-filter>
        <action
            android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
        <category
            android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data
            android:mimeType="image/*" />
    </intent-filter>
```

and in my activity i use codes to delete the selected image if some condition is met, then i used the following code to refresh the gallery.

```
    sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri.parse("file://"+ Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
```

everything works perfect but after deleting,the image is still shown when pressing the back button. the gallery is refreshing only if i quit the currently opened gallery  and reopen it
please help, and sorry for the bad english

Answer (score 1):

I understand that using

```
    sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri.parse("file://"+ Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
```

is resource intensive and, because it mounts and unmounts the SD card, causes problems for other applications running that are using it. You should probably first find a better implementation to refresh the gallery and then see if you can work around the back button issue (will probably need to add something to your overridden onStart() method.)